# remaking strcat, changes not reflecting to pointer

Tags: c, c-strings, strlen, function-definition, strcat

Hello guys so I am learning C and I am creating the `strcat` function and when I print out the values of `dest` at the index `i` concatenate a char at I get that char but when I return `dest` and print it out back in my `main` function the changes aren't reflected. Can someone please help me out? thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int size_s(char *str) {
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (str[index] != '\0') {
        size += 1;
        index += 1;
    }
    return (size + 1);
}

/*
 * @function: strcat
 * @desc: Takes in two char pointers and concatenates them. provided the destination has enough size otherwise undefined behavior can occur. Overwrites the null terminator
 */
char *strcat_s(char *dest, char *source)
{
    int index_of_src = 0;
    int index_of_dest = size_s(dest);

    while (source[index_of_src] != '\0') {
        *(dest + index_of_dest) = source[index_of_src];
        index_of_src += 1;
        index_of_dest += 1;
     }

     // Add Null terminator
 
     *(dest + (index_of_dest + 1)) = '\0';

     return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char firstname[100];
    scanf("%s", firstname);
    char lastname[100];
    scanf("%s", lastname);
 
    int sizeofFirst = size_s(firstname);
    printf("Sizeof first: %d\n", sizeofFirst);
    int sizeofSecond = size_s(lastname);
    printf("Sizeof second: %d\n", sizeofSecond);

    char *concatinated = strcat_s(firstname, lastname);

    printf("%s\n", concatinated);
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? I'm pretty certain that your `size_s` returns a value that is one past the null-terminator, so your `strcat_s` does not overwrite that

Comment: finnaly it works thanks so much I dont know why I dident relize that i was looking too deeply into my strcat function

Comment: `return` is not a function.  Rather than `return (size + 1)`, it is more common to write `return size + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `size_s` returns the index of the character after the zero-terminating character '\0' due to this return statement

```
return (size + 1);
```

So in this while loop

```
 int index_of_src = 0;
 int index_of_dest = size_s(dest);

 while(source[index_of_src] != '\0')
 {
    *(dest + index_of_dest) = source[index_of_src];
    index_of_src += 1;
    index_of_dest += 1;
 }
```

the array pointed to by the pointer `dest` is filled after the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

As a result this call of `printf`

```
printf("%s\n", concatinated);
```

outputs the initially stored string in the array `firstname`.

Rewrite the function `size_s` the following way

```
size_t size_s( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

In turn the function `strcat_s` that should be renamed because there is standard function `strcat_s` can look for example the following way

```
char * strcat_str( char *dest, const char *source )
{
    size_t n = size_s( dest );

    while ( ( *( dest + n++ ) = *source++ ) != '\0' );

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- the `size_s` function really computes the size of the string, including the null terminator, but counting the null terminator is not helping for the task at hand, you should instead compute the *length* of the string, ie: the number of bytes before the null terminator, which is exactly the offset where to copy the second string at the end of the first.
- `*(dest + (index_of_dest + 1)) = '\0';` does *not* store the null terminator at the correct place: it places it one step too far. You should write `*(dest + index_of_dest) = '\0';` or simply `dest[ndex_of_dest] = '\0';`
- the name `strcat_s` may conflict with a library function of the same name defined in the infamous Annex K of the C Standard. A different name is preferable.
- `scanf("%s", firstname);` is a security flaw: sufficient long input will cause a buffer overflow and carefully crafted input may allow the user to execute arbitrary code. Use `scanf("%99s", firstname);` to avoid this.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_strlen(const char *str) {
    int index = 0;
    while (str[index] != '\0') {
        index += 1;
    }
    return index;
}

/*
 * @function: strcat
 * @desc: Takes in two char pointers and concatenates them. provided the destination has enough size otherwise undefined behavior can occur. Overwrites the null terminator
 */
char *my_strcat(char *dest, const char *source) {
    int index_of_src = 0;
    int index_of_dest = my_strlen(dest);

    while (source[index_of_src] != '\0') {
        dest[index_of_dest] = source[index_of_src];
        index_of_src += 1;
        index_of_dest += 1;
     }

     // Add the null terminator
     dest[index_of_dest] = '\0';

     return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char firstname[200];
    char lastname[100];

    if (scanf("%99s %99s", firstname, lastname) != 2)
        return 1;
 
    printf("length of first: %d\n", my_strlen(firstname));
    printf("length of second: %d\n", my_strlen(lastname));

    char *concatenated = my_strcat(firstname, lastname);
    printf("%s\n", concatenated);
    printf("length of concatenation: %d\n", my_strlen(concatenated));

    return 0;
}
```